# Static Backgrounds With Scrolling Content On Top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm interested in emulating the background effect seen here: [**(Link)**](http://themestrong.com/demo/argo/slide.html). Basically it's a static background with scrolling content over top, but there are different background for each "window" section on the page. See below:

[image]

**Scroll down further:**

[image]

My initial thought was to just have one huge static background with each "window image" stacked on top of each other vertically, and then have divs with transparent backgrounds on top, but this seems wrong.

**How can I reproduce this effect?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general:

1. Use `fixed` CSS positioning for the top bar (as mentioned above)
2. Give your foreground container a greater `z-index` than your background container
3. Make the backgrounds of certain sections "invisible" by setting their `opacity` to `0`

You'll want to experiment with the width of your background image and foreground containers to get things right. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

How about you buy that premium them on theme forest that you are trying to copy. There are many parallax scrolling tutorials on the  web that will walk you through this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fixed` css positioning to get the effect of the top bar. Then for the rest of the page I would use some sort of encapsulation `div` that is shifted downward by the height of the top bar using `relative` css positioning. Then for your different page sections just have divs which are stacked one after another and just have different backgrounds.

[Link relating to css positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)